# This Apple ID can't be used to make purchases - InTune/Apple Business Manager

Tags: apple, microsoft-intune, mdm

We have just integrated InTune with Apple Business Manager and turned on the domain Federation which now allows our Azure AD users to log into Apple Devices with their work email address. We have hit an issue with this in that the users can no longer download apps from the App Store, or through the InTune Company portal. The users are presented with a message 'This Apple ID can't be used to make purchases'.

Hoping to get some assistance on this one. The main annoyance here is that the Company Portal cannot be downloaded from the app store without using a personal Apple ID. The secondary annoyance is that once the company portal is installed and the device is enrolled the apps configured through InTune also fail.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

- Purchase licenses through the Apple Business Portal and assign them to your site.
- Create a VPP Token in the business portal and upload it to InTune.
- Sync the token to see your Apps in InTune, when allocating them in InTune you need to click on the Volume Purchased iOS version of the app, assign to a group of the users, but make sure that the license is allocated as Device based.

Comment: thanks, this all makes sense except the last part "device based." where can i go to change it from user to device?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the VPP license for the app from User to Device.